# How i can remove entire tag from XML using Dataweave?

Tags: dataweave, mule4

How i can remove entire tag from my input payload xml . In this payload i need to remove entire borrower  tag .

Payload

```
<users>
<user username="Julian" password="1234"/>
<borrower username="Mariano" password="4321"/>
</users>
```

Expected Output is

```
<users>
<user username="Julian" password="1234"/>
</users>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following DataWeave expression:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
---
{
    "users": payload.users - "borrower"
}
```